# Accessing the controller from a route's beforeModel

Tags: javascript, ember.js, rsvp.js

I would like to access my route's controller from within the beforeSend hook on a route to take advantage of the pause on promise logic.

This is my current workaround to be able to set "category_config" on my controller which is obtained from a promise in beforeModel.

```
Imaging.ReferenceRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Imaging.Ajax, {
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('error_messages', []);
    controller.set('category_config', this.get('category_config'));
    return this._super(controller, model);
  },
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    var categories;
    categories = this._promise("/url/foo/", "GET");
    return Ember.RSVP.all([categories]).then(((function(_this) {
      return function(response) {
        return _this.set('category_config', response[0]);
      };
    })(this)));
  },
  model: function() {
    return Imaging.Document.find();
  }
});
```

In case you are curious my _promise helper is below:

```
_promise: function(url, type, hash) {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    hash = hash || {};
    hash.url = url;
    hash.type = type;
    hash.dataType = "json";
    hash.success = function(json) {
      return Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
    };
    hash.error = function(json) {
      if (json && json.then) {
        json.then = null;
      }
      return Ember.run(null, reject, json);
    };
    return $.ajax(hash);
  });
}
```

How can I do this without having the beforeModel set the 'category_config' on the route, and then set it on the controller in setupController?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested, but I think you could return a tuple with the `Imaging.Document.find()` and the `_promise("/url/foo/", "GET");`, using [Ember.RSVP.hash](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js#hash-of-promises)

```
Imaging.ReferenceRoute = Ember.Route.extend(Imaging.Ajax, {
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('error_messages', []);
    controller.set('category_config', model.category_config);
    return this._super(controller, model.document);
  },  
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      document: Imaging.Document.find(),
      category_config: this._promise("/url/foo/", "GET")
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: this was a much cleaner approach.  Thanks!

Comment: @MarcioJunior This is why I love stackoverflow. This hash is exactly what I needed